# Finding ancestors using absolute path

Tags: xpath, absolute-path, ancestor

I have a bit of a strange situation. I'm probably going to have to write some custom code, but I thought I would post it here in case there was an off chance there is a solution or in case others have a similar problem.

I need to find the nearest ancestor of an element using absolute paths.

Due to some limitations in the environment in which I'm working, I cannot use relative paths. So ancestor, preceding, parent, and the like are not accessible in this instance.

Ex.

```
<root>
  <section>
    <chapter>
      <p id="1"/>
    </chapter>
  </section>
  <section>
    <chapter>
      <p id="2"/>
    </chapter>
  </section>
  <section>
    <chapter>
      <p id="3"/>
    </chapter>
  </section>
</root>
```

Say that I am in p id="2". I want to find the nearest section ancestor. This is typically accomplished with

ancestor::section or even ancestor[1]::section

However, I must use an absolute path. I have no IDs or any other unique identifiers that I can draw from.

I have tried using XPaths like

//section[something here]

but I'm unsure what I can put in the predicate to dynamically find the current section element.

Is it possible to find the nearest ancestor using absolute paths?

This is XPath 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
//section[chapter/p/@id="2"]
```

ie. find a section that contains a chapter that contains a `p` whose id attribute is 2.

Comment: No, I don't have any IDs to draw from. The id in the sample was just for example sake.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Can you keep the section in a variable in the code that implements the whole stuff?